# Using one Nginx server block for multiple sites

Tags: nginx

We have multiple Drupal sites (up to 12) under nginx and we need them to be served by the path.

```
http://example.com/site1
http://example.com/site2
```

I see two ways to do this.

1) Create dummy subdomains so that we can use one server block per site.
NOTE: I'm only showing the relevant lines in the configs below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.localhost;
    root /var/www/site1;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.localhost;
    root /var/www/site2;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;  # _ is used as a catch all domain
    location /site1/ {
        proxy_pass site1.localhost;
    }
    location /site2/ {
        proxy_pass site2.localhost;
    }
}
```

The above requires us to add entries for each site in the /etc/hosts file.
Eg: 127.0.0.1   site1.localhost;

I don't want to have to edit DNS entries globally. It becomes a headache to manage in our environment (multiple cloud servers who come and go, each with multiple sites).

2) Use one server block with location blocks for each site.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _; # _ is used as a catch all domain
    location /site1/ {
        root /var/www/site1;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            ...
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        ...
    }
    location /site2/ {
        root /var/www/site2;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            ...
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Does solution 2) have any impact on scalability or efficiency of nginx? ie: using one server block for everything.

What's the best solution to use generally?

Comment: Hey did you get a solution for this?? I am facing a similar issue!! :P
My question is [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/578435/enabling-multiple-domains-in-a-server-block-of-nginx)

Comment: @coderunner: no, I didn't get any further with this. We're currently using option 1.